# Getting Mono and Firebird Embedded working on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, mono, firebird, firebird-embedded

I was recently looking into Firebird Embedded as a product that could replace SQLite in my project. The thing is, I would like to be able to use the same compilation of my application both on Windows and Linux, and unfortunately with SQLite it's not possible.

Still, I can't get Firebird running on Linux with Mono (haven't tried Windows yet).

Things I've done:

1. Installed `Firebird ADO.NET Provider` from NuGet.
2. Downloaded [32 bit embedded client for Windows libraries](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-2-5-2-upd1/#Win32) and extracted to my bin directory: `fbembed.dll`, `firebird.cfg`, `firebird.msg`, `ib_util.dll`, `icudt30.dll`, `icuin30.dll`, `icuuc30.dll`.
3. Created the connection string with:

   ```
   string fbConnectionString = String.Format ("ServerType=1;User=SYSDBA;" + Password=masterkey;Dialect=3;Database={0};Charset=UTF8", _dbFile);
   FbConnection.CreateDatabase (fbConnectionString);
   ```
4. Still, I get the error, that `fbembed.dll` is not found in the path.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Firebird .NET provider is primarily developed for he Windows platform. The wire protocol implementation works with Mono and under Linux, so it can connect to a normal Firebird server.

The `fbembed.dll` library for Firebird Embedded is specific to Windows and cannot be loaded on linux. The [.NET provider code](https://github.com/cincuranet/NETProvider/blob/master/NETProvider/source/FirebirdSql/Data/Client/Native/FbClient.cs) does have support for Linux, but it looks like you need to specifically compile it for linux. I assume the NuGet package is the default version compiled with support for Windows and Embedded.

Comment: That's what I feared. So SQLite it is. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @moskalak You could add it as a feature request to http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET

Comment: This is not true. The .NET client can load `libfbembed` the same way as `fbembed`.

Comment: You specify the path to `libfbembed.so` in connection string (explicitly) or you can use build for Mono/Linux where the `libfbembed` is supposed to be default name instead of `fbembed`.